# Idiomatic way of checking if a key on a map has a value

Tags: clojure

What is the idiomatic way of checking if a key on a map has a value? For example if we have:

```
=> (def seq-of-maps [{:foo 1 :bar "hi"} {:foo 0 :bar "baz"}])
```

To find out all the maps with :foo == 0, I like:

```
=> (filter (comp zero? :foo) seq-of-maps)
({:foo 0, :bar "baz"})
```

But if I want to find all the maps with :bar == "hi", the best that I can think of is:

```
=> (filter #(= (:bar %) "hi") seq-of-maps)
({:foo 1, :bar "hi"})
```

which I don't find very readable. Is there a better/more idiomatic way of doing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I personally like refactoring this kind of thing to use a clearly named higher order function:

```
(def seq-of-maps [{:foo 1 :bar "hi"} {:foo 0 :bar "baz"}])

(defn has-value [key value]
  "Returns a predicate that tests whether a map contains a specific value"
  (fn [m]
    (= value (m key))))

(filter (has-value :bar "hi") seq-of-maps)
=> ({:foo 1, :bar "hi"})
```

Downside is that it gives you an extra function definition to manage and maintain, but I think the elegance / code readability is worth it. This approach can also be very efficient from a performance perspective if you re-use the predicate many times.

Comment: Nice idea, I like it. Just as an aside, in the code, your final call doesn't seem to match with the `seq-of-maps` you define in the first line.

Answer (score 15):

Idiomatic is subjective, but I'd do

```
=> (filter (comp #{"hi"} :bar) seq-of-maps)
```

or what you did.

Answer (score 3):

clojure.set/index could also be used here

```
((index seq-of-maps [:foo]) {:foo 0})
((index seq-of-maps [:bar]) {:bar "hi"})
```

If you want you can wrap it in a function

```
(defn select-maps [xrel m]
   ((index xrel (keys m)) m))
```

then

```
(select-maps seq-of-maps {:foo 0})
(select-maps seq-of-maps {:bar "hi"})
```

both work - you can also request maps with multiple key/values using index ie:

```
(select-maps seq-of-maps {:foo 0 :bar "baz"})
```

selects all maps containing foo 0 and bar "baz"

Comment: Thinking about this, it seems that this doesn't get the exact behavior you require, since it will return a concrete set of only unique maps, rather than a stream potentially containing duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Your third example of passing an anonymous function to filter seems like one of the more idomatic methods for finding maps with a given value. I found it quite easy to read.

Answer (score 2):

```
user> (def seq-of-maps [{:foo 1 :bar "hi"} {:foo 0 :bar "baz"}])
#'user/seq-of-maps
user> (filter #(-> % :bar (= "hi")) seq-of-maps)
({:foo 1, :bar "hi"})
```

As Pepijn says, I think idiomatic ways vary according to personal opinions.
I sometimes use the `->` macro to extract nested parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine to me. Other possible solution can be to use `for` macro as shown below

```
(for [m seq-of-maps 
      :let [v (:bar m)] 
      :when (= v "hi")] 
   m)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace `zero?` with `(partial = "hi")` like this:

```
=> (filter (comp (partial = "hi") :bar) seq-of-maps)
```